# Search user input

Tags: python, sqlite

I want the user to write their username and to see if their input is in my table, but I don't know how to search for their input.

How to do this (it is where the choice 1 is)?

```
import sqlite3

import sys

conn= sqlite3.connect('log_accounts.db')

c= conn.cursor()

def login():

    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account(forename, age, username , year_group, password)')
    c.execute("INSERT INTO account VALUES ('Hannah', '16', 'Han16', '11', '1234')")
    conn.commit()
    print("----------------------")
    print("| 1- Log in          |")
    print("| 2- Register        |")
    print("| 3- Exit            |")
    choice= input("Please select a choice :\n")
    if choice =='1':
        username= input("Please enter your username: \n")
        password= input("Please enter your password: \n")
        results=c.execute("SELECT username, password"
                          "FROM accounts WHERE username= ?", (username,))
        print(results)



    c.close()
    conn.close()
login()
```

Comment: You don't say what your problem is, but I think you need a space after `password` in your SELECT query.

Comment: I might also suspect you have a typo: `SELECT username, password FROM accounts...` you've named table `account`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute()` returns a cursor object, which you must iterate over to get rows. Each row is a tuple containing the column values (two in this case):

```
results = c.execute("SELECT username, password FROM ...")
for row in results:
    print("found: name = {}, password = {}".format(row[0], row[1])
    break
else:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: It works perfectly, and thank you for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

```

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account(forename, age, username , 
           year_group, password)')
c.execute("INSERT INTO account VALUES ('Hannah', '16', 'Han16', '11', 
          '1234')")
conn.commit()
print("----------------------")
print("| 1- Log in          |")
print("| 2- Register        |")
print("| 3- Exit            |")
username= input("Please select a UserName:\n")
password= input("Please select a Password:\n")

cursor.execute(f"SELECT password FROM account WHERE username={username}")
results=cursor.fetchone()[0]
if results:
   if results==password:
      print("login success!")
   else:
      print("password is wrong")
else:
   print("username is wrong")
```

```